# MvvmCross - Crash on device rotation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm having a crash whenever I rotate my device. I'm using MvvmCross 4.0.0.beta-3 and here is how I have my app setup:

Setup.cs

```
    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        var customPresenter = new MvxFragmentsPresenter();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxFragmentsPresenter>(customPresenter);
        return customPresenter;
    }
```

ShellPage.cs

```
    public abstract class ActivityBase<TViewModel> : MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity<TViewModel>
                                                     where TViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

HomePage.cs

```
    [Activity(
    Label = "Home",
    MainLauncher = true,
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    public class ShellPage : ActivityBase<ShellPageViewModel>, IMvxFragmentHost
    {
        .
        .
        .
        public void RegisterFragment<TFragment, TViewModel>(string tag, Bundle args)
            where TFragment : IMvxFragmentView
            where TViewModel : IMvxViewModel
        {
            var customPresenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFragmentsPresenter>();
            customPresenter.RegisterViewModelAtHost<TViewModel>(this);
            RegisterFragment<TFragment, TViewModel>(tag);
        }

        public bool Show(MvxViewModelRequest request, Bundle bundle)
        {
            if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(MenuContentViewModel))
            {
                ShowFragment(request.ViewModelType.Name, Resource.Id.navigation_frame, bundle);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                ShowFragment(request.ViewModelType.Name, Resource.Id.content_frame, bundle, true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        .
        .
        .   
    }
```

MainFragment.cs

```
    [MvxOwnedViewModelFragment]
    [Register("xxxxx.android.fragments.MainFragment")]
    public class MainFragment : MvxFragment<MainFragmentViewModel>
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

I've posted the code above to show that I'm using the MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity as a base activity, IMvxFragmentHost since my ShellPage is the only page which swaps fragments in/out using a NavigationDrawer, as well as the [MvxOwnedViewModelFragment] attributes on my fragments.

When I rotate I get the following error:

```
    10-20 12:10:02.470 I/MonoDroid( 6108): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
    10-20 12:10:02.471 I/MonoDroid( 6108): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    10-20 12:10:02.471 I/MonoDroid( 6108): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.AppCompat.MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity.RestoreLookupFromSleep ()
    10-20 12:10:02.471 I/MonoDroid( 6108): at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Support.AppCompat.MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity.OnPostCreate (Android.OS.Bundle)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new MvvmCross beta4 which is released today has multiple fixes for this. Also the samples are much updated: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples